# Is "atop" the same as "on" here?

Tags: grammar

> There were many toys scattered **atop** the floor.

Can "atop" be used like "on"?

Answer (score 3):

"Atop" and "on" have the same basic meaning, however "atop" implies that the location is on the top of some object or structure.  In your example: "atop the floor", "atop" sounds strange because the "floor" has no elevation; there is no "top" to the floor.  A good rule to go by is to ask yourself if there is a "top" for the object to be located on.  If the location has some reasonable height/elevation then it makes sense to say "atop".

Examples:

"The top of the mountain" is a location that makes sense; mountains have tops.  Therefore, it makes sense to say: "The man stood atop the mountain."  You could also say: "The man stood on the mountain."

"The top of the carpet" is a location that does not make sense; carpets do not have tops.  Therefore, it makes no sense to say: "The man stood atop the carpet."  Instead, you would say: "The man stood on the carpet."

"The top of the car" is a location that makes sense; cars have tops.  Therefore it makes sense to say: "The young couple sat atop the car and watched the sunset."  You could also say: "...sat on the car..."

"The top of the patio" is a location that does not make sense; patios, like carpets, are flat, and have no tops.  Therefore, it makes no sense to say: "We had our dinner atop the patio."  Instead you would say: "We had our dinner on the patio."

Comment: atop the mountain v.s. on the mountain are different; atop means specifically at the highest part of an object with gradable height, while on means anywhere on said object.  The point about objects needing tops is salient, though.